Azure Workitems Azure REST API POST Request - 503 Service unavailable 0x80070057, Invalid request
I'm trying to programmatically create a issue card in Azure boards using python script.
I'm using a PAT (personal access token).
headers = base64encodedPAT
headers[Content-Type']='application/json-patch+json' 
payload = dictionary_of_different_values_to_set

requesturl=f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Issue?api-version=7.0"
requestcall = requests.post(url=requesturl, headers=headers, data=bytes(json.dumps(payload),'utf-8'))

What did I try:

When I run azure pipeline, I get 'Failed: 400 Bad Request'
When I run it on rest Api testing online, I get '503 Service unavailable 0x80070057, Invalid request'
I referred Microsoft website but not much details
I saw a lot of YouTube videos which show creation of PAT but not on how to use it in pipeline. Not many videos on 'Work item' Apis.

Please let me know what's wrong in my approach or throw some ideas or point me out to good online resources.


I'm trying to programmatically create a issue card in Azure boards using python script.


Use the Work Items - Create REST API to create an issue work item in Azure boards using python script.

Solution 1: Encode the personal_access_token for the Authorization header.
import requests
import base64

# Replace with your Azure DevOps organization and project details
organization = ''
project = ''
personal_access_token = ''  
work_item_type = 'Issue'  # e.g., Task, Bug

# Encode the PAT for the Authorization header
encoded_pat = base64.b64encode(f':{personal_access_token}'.encode()).decode()
# Define the headers
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
    'Authorization': f'Basic {encoded_pat}'
}

# API endpoint for creating a work item
url = f'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${work_item_type}?api-version=7.1-preview.3'

# Data for the new work item
data = [
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "Sample  work item"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Description",
        "value": "This is a sample work item created via REST API."
    }
]

# Make the request to create the work item
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

if response.status_code == 200:
    work_item = response.json()
    print(f"Work item created: {work_item['id']}, title: {work_item['fields']['System.Title']}")
else:
    # Print the raw response content for debugging
    print(f"Failed to create work item: {response.status_code}")
    print(f"Response content: {response.text}")


Solution 2: use the auth=('', personal_access_token) directly in requests.post.
import requests

# Replace with your Azure DevOps organization and project details
organization = ''
project = ''
personal_access_token = ''  
work_item_type = 'Issue'  # e.g., Task, Bug

# API endpoint for creating a work item
url = f'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${work_item_type}?api-version=7.0'

# Data for the new work item
data = [
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "Sample  work item"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Description",
        "value": "This is a sample  work item created via API."
    }
]

# Make the request to create the work item
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json'}, auth=('', personal_access_token))

if response.status_code == 200:
    work_item = response.json()
    print(f"Work item created: {work_item['id']}, title: {work_item['fields']['System.Title']}")
else:
    # Print the raw response content for debugging
    print(f"Failed to create work item: {response.status_code}")
    print(f"Response content: {response.text}")



Use the Azure DevOps Python Api create_work_item to create an issue work item in Azure boards using python script.

from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from azure.devops.v7_1.work_item_tracking.models import JsonPatchOperation
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication

# Replace with your Azure DevOps organization and project details
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/orgname'
project = ''
personal_access_token = '' 
work_item_type = 'Issue'  # e.g., Task, Bug

# Create a connection to the Azure DevOps organization
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

# Get the work item tracking client
wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()

#  Data for the new work item
document = [
    JsonPatchOperation(
        op='add',
        path='/fields/System.Title',
        value='Sample  work item'
    ),
    JsonPatchOperation(
        op='add',
        path='/fields/System.Description',
        value='This is a sample  work item created via API.'
    )
]

# Create the work item
work_item = wit_client.create_work_item(
    document=document,
    project=project,
    type=work_item_type
)

# Print the created work item details
print(f"Work item created: {work_item.id}, title: {work_item.fields['System.Title']}")


I saw a lot of YouTube videos which show creation of PAT but not on how to use it in pipeline.

To use the above python scripts in the pipeline, you can follow the following steps:

Create a secret variable named PAT in your pipeline.


Use the PythonScript@0 task in your pipeline YAML.
YAML sample with three python scripts:


trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- bash: pip install requests
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      import requests
      
      # Replace with your Azure DevOps organization and project details
      organization = ''
      project = ''
      pat = '$(PAT)'  
      work_item_type = 'Issue'  # e.g., Task, Bug
      
      # API endpoint for creating a work item
      url = f'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${work_item_type}?api-version=7.0'
      
      # Data for the new work item
      data = [
          {
              "op": "add",
              "path": "/fields/System.Title",
              "value": "Sample  work item"
          },
          {
              "op": "add",
              "path": "/fields/System.Description",
              "value": "This is a sample  work item created via API."
          }
      ]
      
      # Make the request to create the work item
      response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json'}, auth=('', pat))
      
      if response.status_code == 200:
          work_item = response.json()
          print(f"Work item created: {work_item['id']}, title: {work_item['fields']['System.Title']}")
      else:
          # Print the raw response content for debugging
          print(f"Failed to create work item: {response.status_code}")
          print(f"Response content: {response.text}")
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      import requests
      import base64
      
      # Replace with your Azure DevOps organization and project details
      organization = ''
      project = ''
      pat = '$(PAT)'  
      work_item_type = 'Issue'  # e.g., Task, Bug, 
      
      # Encode the PAT for the Authorization header
      encoded_pat = base64.b64encode(f':{pat}'.encode()).decode()
      # Define the headers
      headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
          'Authorization': f'Basic {encoded_pat}'
      }
      
      # API endpoint for creating a work item
      url = f'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${work_item_type}?api-version=7.1-preview.3'
      
      # Data for the new work item
      data = [
          {
              "op": "add",
              "path": "/fields/System.Title",
              "value": "Sample  work item"
          },
          {
              "op": "add",
              "path": "/fields/System.Description",
              "value": "This is a sample work item created via REST API."
          }
      ]
      
      # Make the request to create the work item
      response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
      
      if response.status_code == 200:
          work_item = response.json()
          print(f"Work item created: {work_item['id']}, title: {work_item['fields']['System.Title']}")
      else:
          # Print the raw response content for debugging
          print(f"Failed to create work item: {response.status_code}")
          print(f"Response content: {response.text}")

- bash: pip install azure-devops
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      from azure.devops.connection import Connection
      from azure.devops.v7_1.work_item_tracking.models import JsonPatchOperation
      from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
      
      # Replace with your Azure DevOps organization and project details
      organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/orgname'
      project = ''
      personal_access_token = '$(PAT)' 
      work_item_type = 'Issue'  # e.g., Task, Bug
      
      # Create a connection to the Azure DevOps organization
      credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
      connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)
      
      # Get the work item tracking client
      wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()
      
      #  Data for the new work item
      document = [
          JsonPatchOperation(
              op='add',
              path='/fields/System.Title',
              value='Sample  work item'
          ),
          JsonPatchOperation(
              op='add',
              path='/fields/System.Description',
              value='This is a sample  work item created via API.'
          )
      ]
      
      # Create the work item
      work_item = wit_client.create_work_item(
          document=document,
          project=project,
          type=work_item_type
      )
      
      # Print the created work item details
      print(f"Work item created: {work_item.id}, title: {work_item.fields['System.Title']}")


Test result:


Thanks for your detailed answer.
I'm following the exact same steps but 400 Bad request error.  I'm a user who is the administrator of the project and belongs to the Project Collection Administrators group. I'm using 'vmImage: ubuntu-latest' image in yml. I have created the PAT with full access scope. I followed the same steps as you listed above. Do I need to link my PAT elsewhere in the project or pipeline before using it in python script. Not sure what's missing

Hi @ProgrammerHGP, I tested the pipeline using ubuntu-latest agent and it still works. Can you please share the yaml you are using and the detailed logs by editing your post?  By the way, if you run the python scripts in your local instead of the pipeline, will it work?
